# saving track titles of internet radio stream to file

Tags: audio, streaming, internet-radio

Every modern program for listening to internet radio streams is capable of displaying the title and artist of the track that is being played (assuming that the radio stream is broadcasting the title and artist).

What I am looking for is a program or other method which can write this data to a file in real time.

Linux or Windows is fine. Addons to an existing program are fine. Someone explaining to me how to extract the data from a raw stream would be...at least a start. Anything better than the only two ideas I've had already (both of which are really horrible) would be helpful.

Lousy idea 1) Run your usual music player program and write a script which takes screenshots of the program window and then hack it out from there

Lousy idea 2) For the stream you're interested in, write a script which e.g. uses wget to fetch a web page containing the information from the radio stream's home page and hack it out from there.

I don't think I really need to say much more about how bad these solutions are. Anyone have a better one??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Foobar2000 in combination with streamripper and foo_run can do this

In my test, I listened to an [online radio](http://www.themashupradio.com/) via Foobar and started the streamripper.exe via foo_run plugin.
In the background, it downloads, cuts, renames and tags the files automatically.

<sub>Screenshot after some minutes to proof</sub>
[image]

#### Software needed

- [Foobar](http://www.foobar2000.org/download) (can be installed in portable mode)
- [streamwriter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamripper/files/streamripper%20%28current%29/) (can also be used without installing, just extract the installer with [Universal Extractor](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=641))
- [foo_run](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_run) (as a normal foobar component it doesn't need a separate installation)

Follow this [guide on hydrogenaudio.org](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=55975&st=0&p=502818&#entry502818) on how to record internet radio streams with Foobar2000

The important part is this foo_run command. You can use relative paths where your foobar folder is the start folder as the screenshot shows

```
<path\to\streamripper.exe> %path% -r -z -u FreeAmp/2.x -d <your\desired\output\path>
```

[image]

Comment: This is surely the right answer and I'll accept it when I get access to a Windows machine and a little time to test it (give me 48 hours or so -- apologies). And many thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I see now my mistake -- I shouldn't have been googling for the answer to my question, I should just have googled for the huge internet community interested in recording streaming audio and gone from there. Thanks.