# Copy track information of a web radio in foobar

Tags: foobar2000, internet-radio

I like to listen to web radios using foobar, v1.3.9. The radios I listen to broadcast the track title and other metadata. Sometimes I want to remember a given song and would like to copy it's name as it appears in the "Title" column. Note that this title is different from the track title displayed in the Properties window. The standard copy function (Ctrl-c or right-click>copy) only copies that title, not actual track name.

According to [this post](https://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=62734), you can customize the copy command. The post is rather old and while I can edit the command, it doesn't seem to change anything. I assume that there should be a "Copy" menu item under [Context menu]>Utilities but I only see "Save as playlist".

Is there a way to enable this command or copy the title in any other way?

I could probably hack something based on [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/645695/saving-track-titles-of-internet-radio-stream-to-file/645714#645714) about a related problem and setting the stream to null but that's kinda messy just for a track name that foobar obviously knows.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't found a solution after reading working through [this old thread](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,69487.0.html)

Comment: I ended up making a small C# app that just copies the window's title. Not ideal but it works for my needs.

Comment: If using that approach (dealing with windows, controls and so on), a better bet may be [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm). Other than that, I might try to get your initial idea working, only when I get to my Windows machine tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File > Preferences > Preferences: Keyboard Shortcuts > press button [Add new]
in Action, select [context] -Copy name(s),
and Key Alt+C(for example).

Apply

[image]
You can also add a line to the context menu.
File > Preferences > Preferences: Context Menu
select the checkbox Copy name(s)

[image]

Comment: Nice, I knew it had to be possible within foobar itself.